# okhttp запрос на сервер

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Ранее использовал такую конструкцию, но сейчас прочитал про okhttp.

В общем, необходимо этот запрос заменить на запрос okhttp. Как это сделать? Помогите пожалуйста)

```
    class request extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("андрес моего сервера?text="+posts);
                   // posts - значение, которое нужно отправить. Допустим, posts будет равно "hello".
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();
}catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("адрес моего сервера?text=" + posts)
        .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
```

Далее либо синхронно (например, внутри `AsyncTask`, как сейчас у вас):

```
try {
    Response response = call.execute();
    String body = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Либо асинхронно с использование колбеков:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        // Обработка ошибки
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        // Обработка результата
        String body = response.body().string();
    }
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!